# Are the Comic-Drawings in Spaced from Simon Pegg?

Tags: props, spaced

In the series [Spaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced) Simon Peggs character is a comic-drawer. I want to know if the drawings shown in the series are really from Simon Pegg or from someone else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [your own link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced):

> 2000 AD artists Jim Murray and Jason Brashill provided the artwork for Tim's comic The Bear, as well as other incidental artwork for the show.

Comment: I was hoping for a more extensive answer, but i must admit i overread that in the wikipedia article.